# Как загнать переменные в массив?

Tags: массивы, php

Как загнать переменные в массив?

```
$arr=array("$a","$b","$aa");
$arr=array($a,$b,$aa);

$a=1;
$b=2;
$aa=3;
$arr=123 ?
```

Comment: Это только я не понял сути вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=1; $b=2; $aa=3;
$arr=array($a,$b,$aa);
echo join('', $arr);  //123
```